# Restart Timer for everyone when anyone press the button

Tags: c#, asp.net, countdowntimer, timespan

I am having an auction page in my website(Live Auction) so i want the functionality to restart the timer for everyone when any of the person press the bid button.But i am only able to do the restart of that person which press the bid button not all person present in Auction.

Here is my code:

In !Page.isPostback()

```
if (Session["AuctionTimer"] == null)
{
     Session["AuctionTimer"] = new CountDownTimer(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:30"));
     (Session["AuctionTimer"] as CountDownTimer).Start();
}
```

a Countdown timer class

```
public class CountDownTimer
{
    public TimeSpan TimeLeft;
    System.Threading.Thread thread;

    public CountDownTimer(TimeSpan original)
    {
        this.TimeLeft = original;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (!TimeLeft.Equals(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00")))
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    TimeLeft = TimeLeft.Subtract(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:01"));
                }
                else 
                {
                    thread.Abort();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

And a restart function is call when the person click bid button:

```
protected void btnBID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  .......
   RestartStopwatch();
}

private void RestartStopwatch()
{
    Session["AuctionTimer"] = null;
    Session["AuctionTimer"] = new CountDownTimer(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:30"));
    (Session["AuctionTimer"] as CountDownTimer).Start();
}
```

Comment: Session state is user specific, look into Application State https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplicationstate?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: can u help me with some code ..

Comment: You also need to notify the clients (browsers) of others I think. Consider using web sockets for example to notify the other clients participating in the auction with minimum delay.

Comment: thank you brother for your help :) @DmitriTsoy

Comment: @OguzOzgul i didn't understand what you are saying

Comment: How do people join the auction? using web browsers? Then how will they know that the timer has been restarted by someone?

Comment: As @OguzOzgul said, you have to connect frontend and backend somehow. You can do it through web sockets. In .NET preferably by using SignalR (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr)